# Unsure how to use ArcGIS API for Python to plot data

Tags: python, json, gis, arcgis

I have queried an API on this link [OSi Open Data Portal](https://data-osi.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/osi::roads-osi-national-250k-map-of-ireland/api) and got a json response.

This is the query URL:
https://services-eu1.arcgis.com/FH5XCsx8rYXqnjF5/arcgis/rest/services/Roads___OSi_National_250k_Map_Of_Ireland/FeatureServer/0/query?where=1%3D1&outFields=*&outSR=4326&f=json

I understand that within the JSON response there is polyline data that can be used to map the roads (under the 'paths' heading of the response). However, my issue is with how to actually plot this data?

I can't figure out what ArcGis libraries or modules can easily just plot this data. Or does the data have to be manipulated into a different form to plot properly?

I tried the following:

```py
import requests
import json
from arcgis.geometry import Point, Polyline, Polygon, Geometry

url = 'https://serviceseu1.arcgis.com/FH5XCsx8rYXqnjF5/arcgis/rest/services/Roads___OSi_National_250k_Map_Of_Ireland/FeatureServer/0/query?where=1%3D1&outFields=*&outSR=4326&f=json'
response = requests.get(url)
```

And then plotted the polylines using the code below:

```
for feature in response.json()['features']:
    display(Polyline(feature['geometry']))
```

However, this just plots each individual road separately and not combined together on a map.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have the arcgis package, you can use the map widget in a jupyter notebook to render a `FeatureLayer` from this feature service directly.

```
from arcgis import GIS
from arcgis.features import FeatureLayer

gis = GIS()

url = "https://services-eu1.arcgis.com/FH5XCsx8rYXqnjF5/arcgis/rest/services/Roads___OSi_National_250k_Map_Of_Ireland/FeatureServer/0"
ireland_road_features = FeatureLayer(url=url, gis=gis)

map_view = gis.map()
map_view.add_layer(ireland_road_features)
map_view.zoom_to_layer(ireland_road_features)
m
```

Hope this helps!